# How to create a new instance with ubuntu12.04 LTS server in GCE

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

How to create a new instance with "ubuntu 12.04 - LTS server" in Google Compute Engine? I have seen there are options for "Centos and Debian", but I couldnt find any option for Ubuntu 12.04.

Is there any steps to create a ubuntu instance in Google Compute engine?

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own image. There is documentation on how to do this at https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/images#buildingimage

Installing from media onto a blank qemu disk as described in this post about FreeBSD has also been successful for me: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gce-discussion/YWoa3Aa_49U/FYAg9oiRlLUJ

Comment: Welcome to Serverfault. Unfortunately, "link only" answers are not considered very useful because they lose relevance very quickly. Please consider using citations and elaborating on the material with your own experience.

Answer (score 0):

As of November 2014, [Canonical and Ubuntu now provide GCE images for Ubuntu](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2014/11/curated-ubuntu-images-now-available-on.html).

You can find more information on how to spin up instances using these images in [the GCE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems#ubuntu).